# How to traverse a character array storing {int, short, ushort,...} more efficiently?

Tags: c++, arrays, type-conversion, deflate

I have a `char data[len]` populated from unzipped data that is read off of a binary file.
I know that `data` can only be of these types: `char, uchar, short, ushort, int, uint, float, double` for which I know exact number of bits needed to represent (`elesize = {8, 16, 32, 64}`).

I just want to traverse the data list and, say, find the `max()`, `min()` or number of occurrences of a given number. and I want to do this without creating another array for memory space concerns.

I have come up with the following but it is slow for example for `len == 34560000`

So I was wondering if anyone has a 'one-liner' or a more efficient way for doing this (either C or C++).

```
char data[len];
double mymax = -std::numeric_limits<double>::max()
for (size_t i=0; i<len; i += elesize)
{
    double x;
    char *r = data+i;
    if (elementtype == "char")
        x = static_cast<double>(*r);
    else if (elementtype == "uchar")
        x = static_cast<double>(*((unsigned char *)r));
    else if (elementtype == "short")
        x = static_cast<double>(*((int16_t *)r));
    else if (elementtype == "ushort")
        x = static_cast<double>(*((uint16_t *)r));
    else if (elementtype == "int")
        x = static_cast<double>(*((int32_t *)r));
    else if (elementtype == "uint")
        x = static_cast<double>(*((uint32_t *)r));
    else if (elementtype == "float")
        x = static_cast<double>(*((float *)r));
    else if (elementtype == "double")
        x = *((double *)r);
    if (x > mymax)
        mymax = x;
}
```

Comment: This code is in principle undefined behaviour, as you are not allowed to dereference a non-char pointer that doesn't point to the correct type. The question of "more efficient" doesn't arise, strictly speaking, if you don't have *any* correct code at the moment.

Comment: so how would you do this? Let's say you knew `data`'s content is uint16_t and you wanted to find the `max()`

Comment: To be truly *correct* in the sense of the standard, you have to copy the data. I can post a generic thing if you like. Oh, whoops, this is C, not C++. Errr... OK, I can try and make a macro if you like.

Comment: @KerrekSB: it's C++, see the `static_cast`s. Anyway, my interpretation of the standard is that you can do it with a `reinterpret_cast<>` to a reference type, but a `reinterpret_cast<>` to a pointer type would violate strict-aliasing.

Comment: @ninjalj: Oh great. I added a C++ solution then. Re punning: You can't get around Doing The Right Thing, no matter which syntactic acrobatics you pull :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Well, The Right Thing isn't memcpy'ing either, due to endianness, etc... I just have the impression that `reinterpret_cast<&type>` and `memcpy` are equivalent from the standard POV, though probably `memcpy` is preferred (type-punning via `reinterpret_cast<&type>` is just mentioned in a comment, IIRC `memcpy` is mentioned in the main text).

Comment: *"for which I know exact number of bytes needed to represent (elesize = {8, 16, 32, 64}"* Uhhh...those are the number of *bits* for those types on some particular machine. On the machine the number of *bytes* would be 1, 2, 4, 8, but you would be well advised to looking into the `sizeof` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A template should do nicely:

```
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
T read_and_advance(const unsigned char * & p)
{
  T x;
  unsigned char * const px = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&x);

  std::copy(p, p + sizeof(T), px);
  P += sizeof(T);

  return x;
}
```

Usage:

```
const unsigned char * p = the_data;
unsigned int max = 0;

while (p != the_data + data_length)
{
  max = std::max(max, read_and_advance<unsigned int>(p));
}
```

---

Scrap this, I thought originally the question was for C.

Here's a macro:

```
#define READ_TYPE(T, buf, res) do { memcpy(&res, buf, sizeof(T)); buf += sizeof(T); } while (false)
```

Usage:

```
int max = 0;
unsigned char * p = data;

while (true)
{
  unsigned int res;
  READ_TYPE(unsigned int, p, res);
  if (res > max) max = res;
}
```

You don't really get around specifying the *type*, though. In C++ this could be done a bit more elegantly.

Alternatively you can wrap it all in one:

```
#define READ_TYPE_AND_MAX(T, buf, max)  \
  do { T x; memcpy(&x, buf, sizeof(T)); \
       buf += sizeof(T);                \
       if (max < x) max = x;            \
  } while (false)

// Usage:
unsigned int max = 0;
unsigned char * p = data;
while (true) { READ_TYPE_AND_MAX(unsigned int, p, max); }
```

Comment: thanks. if possible, I'd like to see your general implementation in C++ for the mentioned types.

Comment: @listboss: Any specific questions? You have to have the documentation of your data stream format; in general, you may have to read variables differently than with a straight `copy`. `copy` is only good on homogeneous systems. And you should use it with fixed-width types like `uint32_t` etc.

Comment: I know the data stream format. I guess my question is how to avoid defining multiple `mymax` variables, becuase I have to return `mymax` to the calling function. That's why I was casting to `double`.

Comment: @listboss: it depends on whether you know the type at compile time or at runtime. If you only know it at runtime, then you have to have some sort of switch, or maybe a lookup table.

Comment: @ Kerrek: Thanks again. This helped a lot. Just for future reference, I had to drop the first `const` from `const unsigned char * const px = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(&x);` to get it compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `elementtype` is loop-invariant, you would better do the comparison only once outside the `for`. By the way, I hope `elementtype` is of type `std::string` or something that meaningfully compares to string literals.

Ultimately, I would write a template function that does the whole processing loop and then call it with the appropiate template argument according to `elementtype`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yes `elementtype` is loop-invariant, and it is std::string. I will try your suggestion but I had the feeling that all those pointer casting and static_cast were the main culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Put the conditional code outside the loop, so the loop runs fast. Try something like this:

```
char data[len];
double mymax = -std::numeric_limits<double>::max()
double x;
if (elementtype == "char") {
  for (size_t i=0; i<len; i += elesize) {
    char *r = data+i;
    x = static_cast<double>(*r);
    if (x > mymax)  mymax = x;
  }
}else if (elementtype == "uchar") {
  for (size_t i=0; i<len; i += elesize) {
    char *r = data+i;
    x = static_cast<double>(*((unsigned char *)r));
    if (x > mymax)  mymax = x;
  }
}else if (elementtype == "short")

..etc..etc
```

Answer (score 0):

As others indicated, you should check the type only once.  Then you should call appropriate sub-function that only deals with one type.  You should also not be casting to doubles for comparing to my_max when the elementtype is not double.  Otherwise you are needlessly converting to double and doing comparisons with doubles.  If elementtype is uint, then you should never be converting anything to double, just compare with a my_max var that is also uint.

Comment: why the emphasis on converting `uint` to `double`?

Comment: Your code is wasting huge amounts of time converting each value to double before doing the compare with my_max.  There's no need to do that.  You should have a per-type function with its own native format variable my_max, and eliminate all static casts.

Comment: I got that part, you specifically named `uint` as the type that should never be converted to `double` and I thought there is something special about it as opposed to other types.

Comment: I meant uint as an example, same applies to all your types